# Jquery confirm window not working on cancel button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, dialog

I have the following code in the javscript to open a confirmation dialog with yes and no options ,but i am facing some problem in opening the confirmation dialog.

```
function ConfirmDialog(obj, title, dialogText) {
    if (!dialogConfirmed) {
        $('body').append(String.Format("<div id='dialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>",
                    title, dialogText));

        $('#dialog').dialog
                ({
                    height: 150,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,

                    close: function (event, ui) { $('body').find('#dialog').remove(); },
                    buttons:
                    {
                        'Yes': function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            dialogConfirmed = true;
                            GetRadWindow().close();
                            if (obj) obj.click();
                        },
                        'No': function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    return dialogConfirmed;
}
```

This is my code on the aspx page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="return ConfirmDialog(this, 'Confirmation', 'Are you sure want to close the window?');" />
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what "some problem" means?

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: Its not entering into the jquery code on the line number 5, flow just ends in the line number 3 when  i am trying to debug the code through firebug

Comment: flow just ends in the line number 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could it be that you are including two versions of jquery in your page 1.4.1 and 1.4.2? Please change that and see.

Also String.Format in javascript? is that some method that you have written? Use [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) instead.

Comment: NO its not working even after changing the code as you suggested

Comment: +1: didn't check properly. you have pretty much written it all

Answer (score 1):

This code reaches Line 3 and sees `String.Format` inside JavaScript and stops execution there.

There is *no* String.Format in jQuery / JavaScript. If you are particular about [using String.Format in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format), create one yourself.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var formatted = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('\\{'+i+'\\}', 'gi');
        formatted = formatted.replace(regexp, arguments[i]);
    }
    return formatted;
};
```

And use it like

```
$('body').append("<div id='dialog' title='{0}'><p>{1}</p></div>".format(title, dialogText));
```